# What verb goes with “mood” in the context of a polite social inquiry?

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context, politeness, salutations, paraphrasing

How would I best ask someone to share their mood with me? It needs to be snappy and easily understood. For example, given these three choices of verb:

1. share your mood
2. express your mood
3. convey your mood

Which of those is the correct verb?

I know I could simply ask *How are you?* but I wondered whether there wasn’t some to ask them a question that specifically involved the word *mood* in its phrasing.

Comment: The snappiest and most universally comprehensible phrasing is "*How are you feeling?*"; if I were forced to use "*mood*", I might say "*Describe your mood*", though that scans a bit clinical.

Comment: All of these are reasonable. What did a thesaurus tell you? What *don't* you like about these options?

Comment: @DanBron As you suggest, *What are you feeling?* or *What's your mood?*

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I'm asking because I'm working on a project that requires the user to express their mood. I was hoping for a snappy verb, similar to `Post on Facebook`, or `Tweet on Twitter`. I need the verb to be easily understandable by a wide audience so I felt "Convey" was perhaps a little over-complex.

Comment: *What are you feeling?* or *How are you feeling?*. I would not say *What's your mood?*, and I don't think most people would.

Answer (score 0):

If this is to be icon text or the label for a button on a page, then "Share your mood" would be best.  IMHO.